# rtpproxy_start_recording() how to use in opensips or kamainlio

Tags: record, rtp, kamailio, opensips

all

how to record a media of  rtp session into a file? and I search a function-rtpproxy_start_recording() in the rtpproxy module,but how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

To start recording you should just call `rtpproxy_start_recording` function in your config file as described in [RTPproxy module opensips documentation](http://www.opensips.org/html/docs/modules/2.1.x/rtpproxy.html#id294580). But you should take in mind that this func could be called only when when new request/reply received:

> This function can be used from REQUEST_ROUTE and ONREPLY_ROUTE.

For instance:

```
route {
  # just forward all in-dialog requests

  if (has_totag()) {
    t_relay();
    exit;
  }

  if (is_method("INVITE")) {
    t_on_reply("MANAGE_INVITE_REPLY");
  }

  t_relay();
}

onreply_route[MANAGE_INVITE_REPLY] {
  if (status=="200") {
    rtpproxy_start_recording();
  } 
}
```

That's just sketch,rtpproxy managing is omitted for simplification.